# Microsoft Linguistic Analysis API example HttpUtility does not exist

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, linguistics

I'm trying to check [Microsoft Linguistic Analysis API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/linguistic-analysis-api), basic example, so I have subscribed and addad my `Key 1` in `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` and `Key 2` into the `subscription key` here `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");`.

Then I add `Newtonsoft.Json` with `Manage NuGet Packages` into the References of Application, even it is not listed in using of particular example `using Newtonsoft.Json; using bNewtonsoft.Json.Serialization;` not sure, I'm new with this tool.

I'm trying to check this example [Linguistics API](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56ea598f778daf01942505ff/operations/56ea5a1cca73071fd4b102bb) for C# to get some natural language processing results for text analysis mainly of Verb and Noun values according to [this example results](http://%20https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/07/28/microsoft-cognitive-services-luis-and-linguistic-analysis-api/)  So I'm not sure if I'm on the right direction with this example, or possible I've missed something to install, maybe I need some additions. I found this [Analyze Method](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Linguistic-Analysis-API/documentation/AnalyzeMethod) not sure how and if I have to use it for this particular goal.

But seems like something is wrong with `var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);` and `HttpUtility` does not exist.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;

namespace CSHttpClientSample
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            MakeRequest();
            Console.WriteLine("Hit ENTER to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async void MakeRequest()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");

            var uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/linguistics/v1.0/analyze?" + queryString;

            HttpResponseMessage response;

            // Request body
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{body}");

            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
            {
               content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("< your content type, i.e. application/json >");
               response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ken White Hello, hope now is better

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new writeable instance of HttpValueCollection by calling System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty), and then use it as any NameValueCollection, like this:

```
NameValueCollection queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
```

Comment: Hello, I tried but it says the method or operation is not implemented

Comment: I think you did not used the Namespace for this class. You have to use System.Collections.Specialized Namespace to access NameValueCollection class.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a reference to System.Web, and possibly to System.Runtime.Serialization.

Comment: Hello, no, same nothing, does not exist